# Rails view specs: can't locate partials in namespaced views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, rspec, rspec2

I trying to get my head wrapped around testing with RSpec. One of the problems I'm running into is getting RSpec to locate partials when calling `render` in a test for a view in the `admin` namespace.

Essentially, in my vieww, I have lots of `render` calls that use the abbreviated syntax, like this:

```
render @products
```

But, I guess because RSpec lacks the context of knowing that this view is in the `admin` namespace, it can't seem to find the partial located in `app/views/admin/products/_product.html.erb`. To get things working, I have to do something like:

```
render partial: 'admin/products/product', collection: @products
```

But, you know, I'm quite attached to the shorter syntax. It's kinda the whole point of following the Rails conventions. The reward for being such a good boy and putting everything in it's proper place, if you will.

So, I was wondering: is there is a way in my RSpec view test to specify that I am testing a view within a certain namespace? Is there some golden nugget that will make this pain go away?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but this link https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/396 might help anyone else (like me) who has faced a similar issue. You can configure where an rspec spec will look for view partials on a spec by spec basis.

Answer (score -1):

If you feel this really is an RSpec isssue, please log it on the [rspec-rails issues](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/new). Based on your general description, this sounds like a rails issue.

When you use `render @products` in a view, that tells Rails to render a [*partial*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials). This is different from a `render` inside the controller action.

According to the [Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables), when you `render @customer`:

> @customer instance variable contains an instance of the Customer model, this will use _customer.html.erb to render it.

What this is leaving out is the path for `_customer.html.erb`. Unfortunately, the current docs make you hunt for this. Under the [collection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections) info, is this gem:

> Rails determines the name of the partial to use by looking at the model name in the collection. In fact, you can even create a heterogeneous collection and render it this way, and Rails will choose the proper partial for each member of the collection:

What this essentially means is that, in your view, when you perform `render @customer`, this attempt to load: `app/views/customers/_customer.html.erb`. Not the namespace you have setup already. If you wish to use the namespace, your model must either already be part of that namespace (i.e. `Admin::Product`) or you must specify the full partial path (as you have already found out).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Everything works as expected (and documented) in Rails. Rails has no problem locating the correct partial to render. It's the RSpec view test that can't locate the correct partial.

Comment: Also, I should add that, contrary to your last paragraph, you **do not** need to namespace your model to render a namespaced partial; you have to namespace your controller.